# How to optimize a MySQL SELECT query with a LEFT JOIN in main query and an INNER JOIN in subquery?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Consider having three tables: `A`, `B` and `C` and the following simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM B
    INNER JOIN C ON (B.bid = C.bfid)
) s ON (A.bfid = s.bid)
```

If the subquery selects too many rows this query will be a drag since MySQL won't use any indices for `A.bfid = s.bid`. This case can get much worse if there are more than one of such subqueries.

Does anyone have any idea how to optimize such scenarios?

Here's the table structures and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE A (aid INT, bfid INT, PRIMARY KEY (aid));
CREATE TABLE B (bid INT, PRIMARY KEY (bid));
CREATE TABLE C (cid INT, bfid int, PRIMARY KEY (cid));

INSERT INTO B VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO A VALUES (4, 1), (5, 2);
INSERT INTO C VALUES (6, 2), (7, 3);
```

With these, the query will output:

```
+-----+------+------+------+------+
| aid | bfid | bid  | cid  | bfid |
+-----+------+------+------+------+
|   4 |    1 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|   5 |    2 |    2 |    6 |    2 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: If you have MySQL 5.6+, you could try enabling [BKA joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bnl-bka-optimization.html) for this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to do this would be to use a pair of LEFT joins, and then determine whether to return B.adid depending on whether a match has been found on C:-

```
SELECT A.*, 
    IF(C.bfid IS NULL, NULL, B.bid), 
    IF(C.bfid IS NULL, NULL, C.cid), 
    IF(C.bfid IS NULL, NULL, C.bfid)
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.bfid = B.bid
LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON B.bid = C.bfid
```

Comment: I'm sorry but there was a problem with the sample in the question which is fixed now.

Comment: Is there any combination of left and inner joins that can not be reduced to this pattern?

Comment: It could get messy if there are (for example) multiple combinations of records on B and C for each record on A.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the Mysql derived tables dont use indexes and using them in the query for 
big database is an issue.

The first thing could be done is to avoid this and use JOINS to gather data from different tables and if the JOIN is done on indexed columns 
then it will be pretty fast and will ignore full table scan. Now if atall JOIN does not serve the purpose and you are left with no option than 
using subquery with dereived table then the alternative is to use TEMPORARY table for the subquery data and index that TEMPORARY table.

To illustrate this lets create the tables and give indexes and will go through the explain for query without using TEMPORARY table
and with TEMPORARY table.

Note that the TEMPORARY table will exist for current session/connection.

```
create table A (aid int ,val varchar(20));
insert into A values 
(1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C'),(4,'D');

create table B (bid int, afid int);
insert into B values
(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,3),(5,2),(6,2),(7,1),(8,2),(9,3),(10,4);

create table C (cid int , bfid int);
insert into C values 
(1,1),(2,2),(3,1),(4,8),(5,6),(6,6),(7,10);

alter table A add index aid_idx (aid);
alter table B add index bid_idx (bid);
alter table B add index afid_idx (afid);
alter table C add index cid_idx (cid);
alter table C add index bfid_idx (bfid);

create TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table 
select 
B.afid from B 
inner join C on B.bid = C.bfid ;

alter table temp_table add index dafid_idx(afid);


EXPLAIN SELECT A.*
FROM A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT B.afid
    FROM B
    INNER JOIN C ON (B.bid = C.bfid)
) s ON (A.aid = s.afid);

+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | A          | ALL   | NULL          | NULL     | NULL    | NULL |    4 |                                |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL     | NULL    | NULL |    7 |                                |
|  2 | DERIVED     | C          | index | bfid_idx      | bfid_idx | 5       | NULL |    7 | Using index                    |
|  2 | DERIVED     | B          | ALL   | bid_idx       | NULL     | NULL    | NULL |   10 | Using where; Using join buffer |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+


EXPLAIN 
select A.* from A
LEFT JOIN temp_table on temp_table.afid = A.aid;

+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref        | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A          | ALL  | NULL          | NULL      | NULL    | NULL       |    4 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | temp_table | ref  | dafid_idx     | dafid_idx | 5       | test.A.aid |    2 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+------------+------+-------------+

However this query also be pretty good without using derived tables as

select 
A.* from A
LEFT JOIN B on B.afid = A.aid
INNER JOIN C on C.bfid = B.bid
```

So depending on what resultset you are looking at you can optimize the query to avoid using derived tables. If the resultset could be gathered using
simply Joining the tables then just use JOIN on index columns.

Comment: I've tested your solution when the derived table is huge, but I'm not sure how it would compare with my query when it is not!

Comment: yes ideally the above solution works for relatively large amount of data and when we are left with no choice but to use derived table. Mostly the performance lies in the query and I guess you have few more answers to optimize the current query. But the issue is each query is different and its very difficult to predict something before you built the query. What many does is they identify the complex queries which will need the derived tables and then use this technique for the rest use index and some query optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with (before the site went down)

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT JOIN 
b on a.aid = b.afid
left join c on b.bid=c.bfid
where not(bfid is null and bid is not null);
```

I reckon it does what the original does. You'd need to try it to know whether it's better.